# Unix; command line to remove all lines containing substring from file

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

I would like to remove all lines containing a ' MCA: ' substring from /var/log/messages using a command line statement.

I tried sed but can not get it to work;
sed -i '/ MCA: /' /var/log/messages
#results in;
#sed: 1 "/ MCA: /": command expected

does anyone know how to do this? does not have to be sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to delete entries and so need to add /d.

```
sed '/MCA\:/d' /var/log/messages
```

This will output the modified file to screen

Once you are happy, run:

```
sed -i '/MCA\:/d' /var/log/messages
```

To commit the changes to the file.